Existing ESTA after acquiring a new citizenship
My girlfriend has a citizenship of a VWP country and a valid ESTA for her passport. Now she acquired a new citizenship (also a VWP country if that matters) in addition to the old one and a will receive a passport for that new citizenship very soon.
Basically the question is, does she need to reapply for a new ESTA even though she still has the original citizenship and the passport she applied for the ESTA with is still valid?
The official FAQ says this

Yes, a new travel authorization via ESTA is required when: (1) the
traveler is issued a new passport; (2) the traveler changes his or her
name; (3) the traveler changes his or her gender; (4) the traveler’s
country of citizenship changes; or (5) the circumstances underlying
the traveler’s previous responses to any of the ESTA application
questions requiring a “yes” or “no” response have changed.

Do the points (1) and (4) apply in this case or are they only for a situation when a new passport replaces the old one, and/or the old citizenship was renounced?

IMHO, point 5 seems relevant?

One question was, if I remember correctly, do you have more than one citizenship?

I somehow assumed point 5 was only about the final page with the eligibility questions, but you're right - it just says "ESTA application questions requiring a “yes” or “no” response."

I think it's probably ok not to get a new ESTA, but it's certainly safer to get a new one, and the cost is fairly modest, so probably worthwhile to avoid worry.

One of the questions asked of ESTA applicants is "Do you have any other citizenships?" (i.e., other than the citizenship you previously disclosed in your application) The OP here will have answered "No" to that question
The official DHS ESTA FAQ contains a link for "When do I need to reapply for an ESTA?" Following that link, the FAQ says an ESTA holder must apply for a new ESTA if:

the circumstances underlying the traveler’s previous responses to any of the ESTA application questions requiring a “yes” or “no” response have changed.

Here, the OP's circumstances are different, and the OP's response to the "other citizenship" question would change from "No" to "Yes".
Thus, the OP should apply for a new ESTA.
